# extracting text from one file and creating new file with that text using linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a sequence file that has a repeated pattern that looks like this:

```
$>g34 | effector probability: 0.6
GPCKPRTSASNTLTTTLTTAEPTPTTIATETTIATSDSSKTTTIDNITTTTSEAESNTKTESSTIAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTSIAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTS"

$>g104 | effector probability: 0.65 
GIFSSLICATTAVTTGIICHGTVTLATGGTCALATLPAPTTSIAQTRTTTDTSEH

$>g115 | effector probability: 0.99
IAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTSIAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTS
```

and so on.
I want to extract the text between and including each >g## and create a new file titled protein_g##.faa
In the above example it would create a file called "protein_g34.faa" and it would be:

```
$>g34 | effector probability: 0.6
GPCKPRTSASNTLTTTLTTAEPTPTTIATETTIATSDSSKTTTIDNITTTTSEAESNTKTESSTIAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTSIAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTS
```

I was trying to use sed but I am not very experienced using it. My guess was something like this:

```
$ sed -n '/^>g*/s///p; y/ /\n/' file > "g##"
```

but I can clearly tell that that is wrong... maybe the right thing is using awk?
Thanks!

Comment: If your goal is to create fasta-formatted files, are you sure you need the dollar sign (`$`)at the beginning? Fasta files have headers that start with `>`, maybe you want to update the example in your question.

Comment: Is each `>g##` string unique in your input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I would use awk for that. I don't think sed can write to more than one different output stream.

Here's how I would write that:

```
< input.txt awk '/^\$>/{fname = "protein_" substr($1, 3) ".faa"; print "sending to " fname} {print $0 > fname}'
```

Breaking it down into details:

1. `< input.txt` This part reads in the input file.
2. `awk` Runs awk.
3. `/^\$>/` On lines which start with the literal string `$>`, run the piece of code in brackets.
4. (If previous step matched) `{fname = "protein_" substr($1, 3) ".faa"; print "sending to " fname}` Take the first field in the previous line. Remove the first two characters of that field. Surround that with `protein_   .faa`. Save it as the variable fname. Print a message about switching files.
5. This next block has no condition before it. Implicitly, that means that it matches every line.
6. `{print $0 > fname}` Take the entire line, and send it to the filename held by fname. If no file is selected, this will cause an error.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

If `awk` is an option:

```
awk '/\|/ {split($1,a,">"); fname="protein_"a[2]".faa"} {print $0 >> fname}' src.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is better than `sed` for this problem. You can implement it in `sed` with

```
sed -rz 's/(\$>)(g[^ ]*)([^\n]*\n[^\n]*)\n/echo '\''\1\2\3'\'' > protein_\2.faa/ge' file
```

This solution is nice for showing some `sed` tricks:

- `-z` for parsing fragments that span several lines
- `(..)` for remembering strings
- `\$` matching a literal `$`
- `[^\n]*` matching until end of line
- `'\''` for a single quote
  End single quoted string, escape single quote and start new single quoted string
- `\2` for recalling the second remembered string
- Write a bash command in the replacement string
- `e` execute result of replacement

Answer (score 1):

#### awk procedure

`awk` allows records to be extracted between empty (or white space only) lines by setting the record separator to an empty string `RS=""`

Thus the records intended for each file can be got automatically.

The id to be used in the filename can be extracted from field 1 `$1` by `split`ting the (default white-space-separated) field at the ">" mark, and using element 2 of the `split` array (named `id` in this example).

The file is written from `awk` before closing the file to prevent errors is you have many lines to process.

**The `awk` procedure**

The example data was saved in a file named `all.seq` and the following procedure used to process it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";} {split($1,id,">"); fn="protein_"id[2]".faa"; print $0 > fn;  close(fn)}' all.seq
```

**tests results**

(terminal listings/outputs)

```
$ ls
all.seq  protein_g104.faa  protein_g115.faa  protein_g34.faa

$ cat protein_g104.faa 
$>g104 | effector probability: 0.65 
GIFSSLICATTAVTTGIICHGTVTLATGGTCALATLPAPTTSIAQTRTTTDTSEH

$ cat protein_g115.faa 
$>g115 | effector probability: 0.99
IAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTSIAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTS

$ cat protein_g34.faa 
$>g34 | effector probability: 0.6
GPCKPRTSASNTLTTTLTTAEPTPTTIATETTIATSDSSKTTTIDNITTTTSEAESNTKTESSTIAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTSIAQTRTTTDTSEHESTTASSVSSQPTTTEGITTTS"
```

Tested using  GNU Awk 5.1.0